# find related items by searching for other items with max no. of similar tags

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am using a tagging system to group items. Basically I add certain tags to an item and I can then find items that are similar to it, by searching the database for other items that contain some or all of the tags, and then ordering the results by the max number of tags for each item. Here's some pseudo code:

```
    product: id, name, description
    tags: id, name
    product_tags: id, product_id, tag_id


    map = new Map<int product_id, int occurances>
    loop product_tags.where(tag_id: [1,2,3]) as |ptag|
        map[ptag.product_id]++
    end
    sort map by max occurrences
    return map.top(6)
```

My question is; how do I create a single mysql query to carry out this task? I am also open to alternative methods of accomplishing this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Here we expect you to have a go at it yourself first and see what happens. Maybe you already have. What happened when you tried various SQL queries? why were you unsatisfied with the result? Why don't you start by doing all the parts you already know how to do, and then have a go at the tricky parts... then come back to us with the parts that you're stuck on, and you can show us what the results are that you're getting and compare with what you expect instead :)

Comment: I have provided pseudo code which shows how I am doing it right now. My method is quite inefficient though as it does the sorting on the server instead of in the database.

Comment: I'm afraid it's really hard to debug real errors in pseudo code... it's like trying to debug a verbal description of your code. If you've actually tried SQL, please include the SQL here (edit your question and add it because formatting in comments is awful). Then we can start to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the product ids ?

I would go with something like this:

```
product_ids = ProductTag
             .joins("INNER JOIN product ON products.id = product_tags.product_id")
             .where("tag_id IN (?)", [1,2,3])
             .select("product_id, count(product_id) as product_count")
             .group("product_id")
             .order("product_count DESC")
             .limit(6)
             .map(&:product_id)
```

Then, you can do something like this if you need the products:

```
Product.find(product_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will test it and get back to you.